# Move db from 9.6 to 11.6 postgres server

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

After moving a database from postgres 9.6 to 11.6 we are having performance issues running some queries.

- Have two postgres servers running in parallel. 9.6 and 11.6. Bother are AWS RDS`s.
- Used the `pg_dump` command to dump the database to a file (11.6 postgres tools). Connected to RDS running Postgres 9.6. (`PGPASSWORD=<password> pg_dump -Fc --host=<hostname> --port=5432 --username=<username> -f /tmp/filename.dump --exclude-table-data 'table_a' --exclude-table-data 'table_b' --exclude-table-data 'table_c' --exclude-table-data 'table_d' <dbname>`
- Used the `pg_restore` command to load the database to a file (11.6 postgres tools). Connected to RDS running Postgres 11.6. (`pg_restore -Fc -d $PGDATABASE -v -j2 <filename>`

The database restored and all seemed ok however a small number of queries are taking a very long time to run or failing.

Is there something we missed or another way we should have done this? We have run `ANALYZE` but it didn't help.

Comment: Did you also run VACUUM?

Comment: Yep, also ran VACUUM. No difference.

Comment: In that case you need to capture a bad query and look at the execution plan with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`.  Maybe auto_explain (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auto-explain.html) could help there.  Or for the ones failing rather than being slow, you can grab the query text from the error message and just do `EXPLAIN` (no ANALYZE, as that depends on the query succeeding) on it in both databases.